# Unable to extract individual script tags with NSRegularExpression regex

Tags: ios, regex

I'm doing a regex for any character except string on an HTML file.  Basically I'm writing a method to remove all the `script` tags.

The problem is that it just looks for the first `<script>` tag and then the very last `</script>` and returns just one result.  I've tried a bunch of stuff but I can't make it pick up all the intermediary ones.

The regex'es I worked out are: `"<script[^>]*>((?!script).)*</script>"` which returns me nothing, but I believe is closer to what I need and `"<script[^>]*>.*</script>"` which returns me everything as single match.

Here is my code.  The `str` variable is a string that contains 3 matches.  You should be able to just run the code.

```
NSString *str = @"<script type=\"text/javascript\">function setDisqusUrl(){var _loc = window.location.href;disqus_url = _loc.split(\"?\")[0];}var disqus_url;setDisqusUrl(); var disqus_shortname = 'rubydocbeta'; var disqus_shortname = 'ruby-doc';   (function() {      var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;      dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';      (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);   })();</script><script type=\"text/javascript\">function setDisqusUrl(){var _loc = window.location.href;disqus_url = _loc.split(\"?\")[0];}var disqus_url;setDisqusUrl(); var disqus_shortname = 'rubydocbeta'; var disqus_shortname = 'ruby-doc';   (function() {      var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;      dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';      (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);   })();   </script><script type=\"text/javascript\">function setDisqusUrl(){var _loc = window.location.href;disqus_url = _loc.split(\"?\")[0];}var disqus_url;setDisqusUrl(); var disqus_shortname = 'rubydocbeta'; var disqus_shortname = 'ruby-doc';   (function() {      var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;      dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';      (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);   })();   </script>";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] 
              initWithPattern:@"<script[^>]*>((?!script).)*</script>"       
                      options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators 
                        error:nil];

NSArray *results = [regex matchesInString:str 
                                  options:NSMatchingWithTransparentBounds 
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

for (int i = 1; i <= results.count; i++) {
  NSTextCheckingResult *result = [results objectAtIndex:(results.count - i)];
  NSLog(@"======================");
  NSLog(@"%@", [str substringWithRange:result.range]);
}

NSLog(@"results count: %i", (int)results.count);
```

Comment: I am doing this so that I can use `NSXMLParser` instead of a third party HTML parser library.  I started off by just removing `<!-- comment tags -->` (as `NSXMLParser` can't deal with it) and just decided to do some extra cleaning up while at it.

Comment: @linuxios really wished I didn't have to do all that tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script[^>]*>.*?</script>

               ^^
```

make your search `non greedy`.

Comment: If you have to use regexps, this is absolutely the right answer.

Comment: thank you.  I obviously need to learn to read the documentation :)